# How to create a custom frame with buttons in it...?

Tags: .net, winforms

Hi can anybody tell me how to create a custom made frame similar to the pic that i have posted here. The frame should be re sizable based on the buttons placed in it.[image]

The uploaded pic might give a better idea, i want to create something similar to that. So how to create such frames in windows form?

My code:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        int start_x = Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text);
        int start_y = Convert.ToInt32(textbox2.Text);

        //Clear out the existing controls, we are generating a new table layout
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();

        //Clear out the existing row and column styles
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();

        //Now we will generate the table, setting up the row and column counts first
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = start_x;
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = start_y;

        for (int x = 0; x < start_x; x++)
        {
            //First add a column
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

           for (int y = 0; y < start_y; y++)
           {
                //Next, add a row.  Only do this when once, when creating the first column
                if (x == 0)
                {
                    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
                }

                //Create the control, in this case we will add a button
                Button cmd = new Button();
                cmd.Width = 120;
                cmd.Height = 60;
                cmd.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                cmd.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
                cmd.Text = string.Format("ds");
                cmd.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnDynamicButton_Click);

                //Finally, add the control to the correct location in the table
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cmd, x, y);
            }
```

But I don't know how to create that frame and arrange it accordingly.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read at least a tutorial on Windows Forms?

Comment: Well, if you have not tried anything you won't do anything. Please, read and try something about winforms and you'll be able to do this by yourself. Just an input, your frame will be resizeable if you take in consideration width and height of all controls in it. Enjoy it.

Comment: @Sylca: Well now that i have added the code, so now can u guide me plz.. Hope u got my problem, it just that i need to create a frame with buttons placed inside it and the frame should be re-sizable.

Comment: @Y.Ecarri: I have added the code of what i have tried, so can u guide me from here on..?

Comment: It's not clear what you need. What are the white spaces in the layout? Do you expect to be able to write text in them? do you want to display pictures in them or are they just a few white boxes? What are the buttons that appear at the botom for? Do you expect the layout to reorganize according to the button pushed?

Comment: @Y.Ecarri: The image shows windows form in which their is a frame containing 4 buttons(white in colour) arranged in a matrix of 2x2, likewise i want to create a frame and place buttons in it. Here the frame should increase or decrease in its size based on the buttons placed in it. Also the matrix for buttons in the frame is decided by the client. Also let me know how to embed those green buttons which is visible in the image that is posted.

Comment: What do you mean by "frame"? A Panel control?

Comment: @Y.Ecarri: Its actually a container in which the buttons are placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a new Windows Form.

2) Place and size some buttons in it.

3) Add a handler for the Resizing event in the form.

4) Adjust size and position of the buttons according to the new size of the window in the resize event.

There are 6 container conrols in .Net 4: Panel, SplitPanel, TabControl, TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayoutPanel. I think a Panel would fit your needs, so start by adding a Panel control to your Form. Resize it as needed.

Place one command button in the panel. Resize it as needed. Select it and press F4 to activate the properties window. Find the FlatAppearance property and change it to Flat. Change the Background color to White and the Text property to a empty string. Now you have ONE white button. Copy it and paste 3 times. Place the buttons as needed.

For the green buttons: start creating a bitmap for each one of the desired images. Create one command button, change it to Flat style and replicate it as before. For each button, edit the Image property and import the images you created.

Once you have the "static" layout, you need to do some math. You have to decide which resizing strategy will you use:

a) Proportional: All the magnitued expand proportionally to the container.

b) Pseudo-proportional with fixed spacing. You set a fixed separation between the buttons and resize them maintaining the same separation.

As "a" is the easiest way, i'll tell you how to do it.

1) Create a table like this. Fill the values with the positions of the buttons in the container when the form is in the designer (not running)

[image: Position of each button in the layout]

2) In the Resizing event:

2.1) Determine the scaling factors for X and Y. Lets call them factorX and FactorY

2.2) Each button new position will be its original position multiplied by the scaling factor. For example, for Button1, and supossing that the screen expands 2x in wide and 3x in heigth:

Top: 10 x 2 = 20
Left: 10 x 3 = 30

2.3) Each button size will be the original size adjusted by the factor:

Width: 100 x 2 = 200
Heigth: 100 x 3 = 300

Bottom: 20+200 = 220
Right: 30+300 = 330

And so on...